# If G is a secure PRG and G' is a function of G, is G' secure?

Tags: stream-cipher, pseudo-random-generator

For example: for secure PRG `G` if I have a `G'` s.t. `G'(k) = G(k)||0`, is `G'` necessarily secure? This question is not for the above example only but for any other possibilities as well. My thinking is that since `G` is secure (ADV is negligible and PRG is unpredictable), then no matter what I do with `G` to make `G'`, `G'` is secure.

Comment: This feels like a homework question to me. Is it?

Comment: My question is not the HW problem, it is something I am gathering after doing it and wondering if it is true.

Comment: Your example is already sufficient to contradict your intuition. If the last bit is always zero can the output of $G'$ be indistinguishable from uniformly random strings?

Comment: Oh man, it is distinguishable. Thank you. So is it the advantage in the case of my example that would make G' insecure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the function $G'(k) = f(G(k))$, where $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.  Clearly, $G'$ is a function of $G$.  Is $G'$ a secure PRG?

Answer (score 4):

Of course not. We can define a simple statistical test A as:

A(x): If the last bits of x is 0 output 1. Otherwise output 0.
Then 
$$Pr[A(G(k)) = 1]= 0$$
for random $k \in K$, where $K$ is the key space, and 
$$Pr[A(r)=1 ]=1/2$$
for random $r \in \{0,1\}^n$. So
$$ADV(A,G) = |0-1/2| = 1/2$$ 
Which is clearly non-negligible.

Comment: This question is almost 3 years old, and this is just a repetition of what DrLecter wrote in the comments. Even for a full answer, it is lacking the main statement that the example in the question isn't a PRF in the first place. Since the question was explicitly about general constructions for $G'$, this answer doesn't adress the question.